# how to execute test data level execution in parallel mode for one test case

Tags: selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am opening multiple instance of browser for each data set but all the input data is getting entered only in one instance/session instead of each data set in each instance. I am using selenium and TestNG

```
@DataProvider(name="URLprovider", parallel=true )
private Object[][] getURLs() {
  return new Object[][] {
      {"Fist data"},
      {"Second Data"},
      {"3 data"}
  };
 }

 @Test(dataProvider="URLprovider",threadPoolSize = 3)
 public void testFun(String url){
    BaseDriver baseReference = BaseDriver.getBaseDriverInstance();      
  System.out.println("Test class"+url +"=" 
       +Thread.currentThread().getId());

    driver = baseReference.initBrowser();       
    driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/"); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='search']/div/input")).sendKeys(url);

}
```

So here i am opening three browser instance parallel (as we have 3 set of data in @dataprovider ) and entering value in text box. But while executing the code 3 instance is getting opened but test data value is entered only in one instance... but my expectation is to enter one data in one instance.

Comment: provide logic used here BaseDriver.getBaseDriverInstance();

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your test code.

The test code that you shared as part of `testFun()` seems to suggest that you are making use of the same `WebDriver` instance amongst all of your `@Test` iterations.
You haven't shown us what `BaseDriver baseReference = BaseDriver.getBaseDriverInstance();` looks like, but going by your issue I am assuming that its returning the same webdriver instance.

That explains why all of your test methods seem to be sharing the same webdriver instance.

To fix this issue, you would need to do one of the following:

1. Move your webdriver instantiation logic inside your test method i.e., `testFun()` (or)
2. Create a `@BeforeMethod` configuration method which would be responsible for creating a browser instance and persist that within a `ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>` instance and your test method viz., `testFun()` gets the current thread's webdriver instance via `driver.get()` [ here driver is of type `ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>`. Don't forget to declare `driver` as a static variable.

Comment: Pls accept my answer if it helped. It also closes the question.